# Composer Require Out of Memory

Tags: php, composer-php

So, I've poured through the stack and git bug threads on this and can't seem to find anything that helps. This is a dev server, centos linux, running php 7.2, roughly 12Gb of available RAM and swap.

Running out of memory on composer require or composer update.

I have set memory usage to -1, and verified that the CLI version of php is set to -1.

```
php -i | grep memory
memory_limit => -1 => -1
```

I have run: composer self-update, and it is at the most recent version.

I have tried running via: `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer require ...`

And, in every instance, it is still running out of memory just trying to use require. Is there somewhere composer is overriding my limits set in php.ini or runtime setting. It appears to maxing out at around 200Mb.

Updating:

```
php -v
ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.0.28 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 09:28:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Output of composer -vvv requre:

```
$ composer -vvv require willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem: valid
Executing command (/home/XXXXXXXX/gateway): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/XXXXXXXX/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/gateway/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin PackageVersions\Installer
Running 1.6.3 (2018-01-31 16:28:17) with PHP 7.0.28 on Linux / 4.15.12-x86_64-linode105
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-04.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-07.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-10.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2018-01.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-willdurand$jsonp-callback-validator.json from cache
Using version ^1.1 for willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator
./composer.json has been updated
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (/home/XXXXXXXX/gateway): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/XXXXXXXX/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/gateway/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin PackageVersions\Installer_composer_tmp0
Reading ./composer.lock
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-04.json from cache
Reading /home/XXXXXXXX/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-07.json from cache

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 196608000) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php on line 574

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 196608000) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php on line 78
```

Comment: Does it fail on any require? Or just for certain packages?

Comment: I imagine it would be all of them. If I'm not mistaken, require essentially runs update subsequently. I'll find something simple to test with though.

Comment: It's any package, just tried with a few others. Going to revert back to php 7.0.xxx and see if there might be a problem with php 7.2.3.

Comment: Note: require does *not* run a subsequent update.

Comment: Post the output of `php -v` and `composer -vvv require <some small package>`?

Comment: Updated. Switched to php 7.0 and same result.

Comment: See [this post](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5863). `cPanel has a "forkbomb protection" option that limits ( php | command-line ) processes to around 180~190mb of memory.`

Comment: Good grief, that was it. No idea why it was enabled on this server. Had to fully reboot to get it to stop restricting memory. Thank you very much